# Why can't I install discord.py?

Tags: python, windows

I'm trying to code a bot in python with visual studio code, when I try to install it in cmd it just gives me a error.

> Failed to build multidict yarl
>
> ERROR: Could not build wheels for multidict, yarl which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly.

Someone please help :(. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TwvIN.png)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because only including an image of an error is not an adequate substitute for text of the error.

Comment: Could you please include some more details about your setup? For example, what version of Python do you have installed? Are you trying to install the module just like `pip install discord.py`, or are you trying to clone the Github project?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the image provided, the error message gives instructions to install "Microsoft C++ Build Tools". Refer to the line starting with "error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required"

This can be downloaded from Microsoft: https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/